# Get correct IP address using $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]

Tags: php, server, cloudflare

I am using following code :

```
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

I echos my IP address as `108.162.225.189` which is somewhere in US. My actual IP address is `59.179.64.246`. Is it because I am using cloudFlare? CloudFlare also says

> CloudFlare sits between your visitor and web server. So, the CloudFlare connecting IP matters only for any programs that read logs directly from your web server (like awstats).

Is CloudFlare causing this problem? How can I get the correct IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the shown IP (108.162...) is a CloudFlare IP. But CloudFlare should provide addtional information. Try this:

```
$ip = 
  isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])?
     $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]:
     $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
  ;
echo $ip;
```

Further information: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170856-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-vBulletin-

Answer (score 0):

You normally can't see your address without tricks because of the cloudflare proxy.

But anyway, you can try grabbing it by the following script

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])){
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
}else{
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Let me know if it works.
Source : http://wp2x.com/get-cloudflare-visitor-ips-php/